# How to set such soap header (php)

Tags: php, soap

I've been sent this example for a soap query:

```
POST https://000.0.0.0:8181/wsForWeb/webService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: Basic username:password
Content-Length: 293
Host: 000.00.00.00:8181
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws/">
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  ....
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I send those headers in soap? Usually I'd use

```
$client = new soapClient(...);
$clHeader = new SoapHeader(..., array('
            'authorization' => 'Basic .......',
            'Host' => '000.000.00.00.0',
            ));
$client -> __setSoapHeaders($clHeader);
```

But I get authentication error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in your soap Header the login credentials

```
$params = array(
   "login" => "username", 
   "password" => "password", 
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlURL, $params);
```

Where the $wsdlURL is the variable with the url of the server where the Soap calls are located.

This is the most common way to implement a Soap Client with Basic Auth

Reference to the PHP official documentation : [Link.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you, giovaZ. That approach was the firs one I used. With no luck - authentication error. That's why I went to setting a header. Still with no luck. Should I ask some extra question to server owner? he said that server expects a header exactly as: 'Authorization: Basic username:password' but I can't get how exactly should I pass that data. I

Comment: It's strange because the method i've posted is the standard way to implement a basic soap Auth. I think you should check the header you're sending by this method http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php and check that the credentials you use are correct.

Comment: Thanks, solved. At the end tje problem was at the other side.